# Best way to send data & automatically consume it with C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a server A in which a C# program is responsible for reading data from a DB, JSON serialize data & send this JSON to another server.

On a server B, I wish that a process been automatically executed when some data is received from server A.

Server A & server B are not in the same local network, but they are both connected to the internet.

I saw in the internet few methods for sending data with C# (such as HTTP, WCF, FTP) but I don't know which is the best for my purpose and how to setup the send/receive system on server A & B?

Thanks.

Comment: WCF is generally considered a dead technology.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your description, Server B would just be some server application (even as simple as a WebAPI app) and Server A would just make requests to that application.  Seems straightforward enough, what's the problem?

Comment: You are not missing anything, server A send some JSON to server B which consume this JSON to perform some INSERT/UPDATE to a DB. The problem is that I don't know how to do that, I don't what I am supposed to set up on both side to make the system work.

Comment: Are you talking about web servers (for server A, server B) or are you talking about a server application or windows service (i.e. not hosted or web based)?

Comment: I think that I'm supposed to do a POST containing the JSON from server A to B, and I have to have a listener in server B which perform the process since it received data. I've never done WebAPI so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt I'm talking about application servers. For now, there is no web services in those servers, and I would know what I have to install / setup on both side for my purpose.

Comment: The servers are not in the same local network but they are connected to internet. Can you access one from the other? If so how? depending on A can request B or B can request A, you can establish a communication channel. If that is not possible, you'll have to use a third server that can do something like Pub/Sub. Your information so far is not enough to decide on HTTP, WCF etc.

Comment: @SandeepDesai For now I don't know how to access a server from the other one. All I know is that both are connected to the internet, and I want to setup something to be able to communicate through internet between those servers.

Comment: @Arnaud: Based on this description, create a WebAPI application and host it on Server B.  Then in whatever application is running on Server A you would use the WebAPI client libraries to make requests to Server B.  (Or you could even just manually issue HTTP requests, there are several ways to do it.)  I don't see where you're stuck.  If you're asking how to build these applications at all in .NET then what you're looking for are introductory tutorials, there are many to be found.

Comment: @David I was stucked in the what to do part :) Before you said I was not aware about the fact I have to create a WebAPI on server B. So I will search for tutorials to create a WebAPI. Thank you for your advises !